# Using the "indevr" font with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, ampersand

I plan to use the Indevr font (for typing Samskrit) which can be found at the bottom of this page: http://www.pratyatosa.com/?P=41

For some reason "&" and "_" symbols are not being rendered by the font. This is my command line:

`\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}`

`\usepackage{fontspec}`

`\newfontfamily\idr{Indevr}`

`\begin{document}`

`\begin{flushleft}
{\idr AíaXaqiTaSahóai<a MauNaYaae Yae Da*Tav]Taa" ) \\
ANviXa+aNv]Ta& TaSYa k-aEMaarb]øcair<a" )) 22 ))}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}`

The output which i am getting is [image]

whereas the output which i should be getting is [image]

The starting word of in the second line of the verse has the error. M& is the command used for producing the dot above M and it's creating a problem. The error shown is

> Misplaced alignment tab character &. I can't figure out why you would
>   want to use a tab mark here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy
>   is simple: Just type `I\&' now. But if some right brace up above has
>   ended a previous alignment prematurely,

Comment: as the error message says you need `\&` as `&` has special use in latex for table cells. Or if you don't need alignments use `\catcode \`\&=12` to make `&` a normal character. similarly `_` is special for math mode subscripts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Dear DAvid, could you please write your comment as an answer so that i can accept it explaining it a bit more. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says you need `\&` as `&` has special use in latex for table cells. that is

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}
```

similarly `_` is special, denoting a subscript `x_2` making *x*<sub>2</sub>

Or if you don't need alignments or subscripts in this document use

```
\catcode `\&=12
\catcode `\_=12
```

to make `&` and `_` into a normal characters.